# Need to way to eliminate reversals of original transactions in a df

Tags: r

I have a df containing hundreds of columns and millions of rows. Below is a small snippet of the df containing details of just one account

```
AccountNo<-c(11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344)
transactionstatus<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
Grossamt<-c(-44.49667,44.49667,-16.58250,16.58250,-21.10364,21.10364,19.24353)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(AccountNo,transactionstatus,Grossamt))
```

The 1 in the transactionstatus column represents reversal of the original transaction so what i want the code to do is for each account number, see if there's a 1 in the transactionstatus and then look for the equivalent gross amount as both the gross amount would be equal and finally delete both the rows so in my case this would be the result for account number 11223344

Output

```
(11223344,0,19.24353)
```

Edit

Ran into a different scenario

```
AccountNo<-c(11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344,1122334)
transactionstatus<-c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
Grossamt<-c(-44.49667,-44.49667,29.01750,44.49667,29.01750,-29.01750,-21.10364,21.10364,44.49667)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(AccountNo,transactionstatus,Grossamt))
```

Expected output

```
29.01750
```

Comment: what is the expected output for Edit

Comment: Going by df %>%
   group_by(AccountNo) %>%
   filter(!Grossamt %in% Grossamt[transactionstatus == 1]), it will just delete everything because grossamounts are same  but in my example, i still want -44.49667 as its not reversed

Comment: Your values are all the same, so wouldn't that delete everything

Comment: yes, but there are two 1's so it should cancel only two 0s, fifth one should remain there

Comment: Okay, that logic was not mentioned in the post.

Comment: Yes, my bad, just ran into this scenario

Comment: Also, are we doing the logic on the values in 0's versus 1 for equal lengths

Comment: Yes, that would be it.

Comment: This also bring another logic as well.  Suppose you have two 1's and 1 0 or for a single 'AccountNo', if the transactionstatus is 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1.  what would be the comparison

Comment: There will always be equal number of 0's or more. Never less than the 1s

Comment: i.e. my point is that if the 1s and 0s are not always adjacent, would you compare those separately or as a single block of 1s and 0s

Comment: Oh yes, Separately!

Comment: can you please update with a better example as this can also lead to different issues

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: OP can you check your example data carefully - the length is inconsistent.  Why is the expected output `44.49667` when there are two transactions for this amount and two that have been reversed?

Comment: yup, you're right, edited.

Comment: I would say that it is better to post as a new question because the original logic was changed a lot

Comment: I think i have found a column that is a unique identifier in that if there are two paired transactions with one cancelling the other one out, the identifier is the same. Your solution works with this approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `filter` the rows where the 'Grossamt' is not (`!`) `%in%` in the subset of 'Grossamt' i.e. where 'transactionstatus is 1

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(!Grossamt %in% Grossamt[transactionstatus == 1])
#  AccountNo transactionstatus Grossamt
#1  11223344                 0 19.24353
```

If there are many 'AccountNo', do a `group_by`

```
df %>%
   group_by(AccountNo) %>%
   filter(!Grossamt %in% Grossamt[transactionstatus == 1])
```

---

Or another option is `anti_join`

```
anti_join(df, df %>% 
      filter(transactionstatus == 1), by = c('AccountNo', 'Grossamt'))
#  AccountNo transactionstatus Grossamt
#1  11223344                 0 19.24353
```

#### Update

Based on the new updated dataset, we can create a new grouping column based on the number of 1s per each 'AccountNo' and do the comparison

```
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(AccountNo) %>% 
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), sum(transactionstatus) *2, n())), .add = TRUE) %>%
    filter(!Grossamt %in% Grossamt[transactionstatus == 1]) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn, -grp)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  AccountNo transactionstatus Grossamt
#      <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  11223344                 0    -44.5
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(df, !Grossamt %in% Grossamt[transactionstatus == 1])
```

CAUTION: The values are in 'Grossamt' are float, so there could be precision involved.  The `%in%` looks for exact matches.  It may be better to `round` to 2 or 3 decimals

```
subset(df, !round(Grossamt, 2) %in% round(Grossamt[transactionstatus == 1], 2))
```

Comment: You added the caution and made it a perfect, thank you!

Comment: I don't think these will work if a later transaction is the same amount as an earlier reversed transaction.  With millions of rows, this is likely to be a problem.

Comment: @27ϕ9 I just tested this on an account and yes it ran into that problem where it deleted all rows with same gross amount. A solution could be to just delete one row for each 1 in the transaction status and not everything?

Comment: Just gave a better example

Comment: @akrun - Am I missing something?  If it's arranged and grouped by absolute amount then anything after the cumsum crosses zero is a transaction that wasn't reversed.

Comment: ok, my point was based on your original solution.  With edits, I can't say.  Also, the logic is still vague to me

Comment: @27ϕ9  By `arrange` ing 'Grossamt' you are breaking the order of 'transactionstatus' i.e. it is now comparing different sets of 'transactionstatus' as a block

Comment: @akrun - That's true but there's nothing in OPs post that indicates that this matters.  The ultimate goal seems to find the unpaired transactions so it's all the same if you're breaking it down by two or looking at it as a whole.

Comment: @27ϕ9 my point is that if there are multiple values in 0s that are same it will be grouped together with your `arrange`. Ultimate aim is to find the unpaired transaction, but it also depends on the tranactionstatus

Comment: @akrun - The transaction status is implicit in the value (that are cancelled out or not when they are summed) so I don't think it matters but happy to admit I might be thinking about it completely wrong.  Anyway, might return to this later but to help me understand your point feel free to provide an example where this approach fails if you're so inclined.

Comment: @27ϕ9 With a question that was changed multiple times, I think it is fair not to discuss these thiings.  My point is about the transactionstatus duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Without a paired transaction id, you could try arranging the data (although this introduces some overhead with millions of rows), grouping on absolute amount, and filtering using `cumsum()`:

```
df %>%
  arrange(Grossamt) %>%
  group_by(tmp = abs(Grossamt), AccountNo) %>%
  filter(cumsum(Grossamt) > 0)

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   tmp [1]
  AccountNo transactionstatus Grossamt   tmp
      <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1  11223344                 0     29.0  29.0
```

Data:

```
structure(list(AccountNo = c(11223344, 11223344, 11223344, 11223344, 
11223344, 11223344, 11223344, 11223344, 11223344), transactionstatus = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), Grossamt = c(-44.49667, -44.49667, 29.0175, 
44.49667, 29.0175, -29.0175, -21.10364, 21.10364, 44.49667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```